# How to iterate over the rows of a csv file and drop based on the value of a particular column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, jupyter

Basically I need to remove certain rows from a csv file where the value of 'County' column does not contain the word county. I'm trying to push that back into my dataframe but, I'm getting an index error.

```
chd = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv')

for index, row in chd.iterrows():
    if 'County' not in row['County']:
        chd = chd.drop(chd.index[[index,3]])
```

I get the following error:

IndexError: index 2959 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2909

Given the following two rows. I would like the get rid of the first row.

```
STATECODE   COUNTYCODE  State   County             Some_Column
1           0           AL      Alabama            9,508
1           0           AL      Alabama County     9,508
```

I have since tried the following which doesn't seem to remove any rows. If i print the data frame it remains the same.

```
chd = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv')
chd[chd['County'].str.contains('county', case=False)]
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of the filter operation: `chd = chd[chd['County'].str.contains('county', case=False)]`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC then you can do `chd[chd['Count'].str.contains('county', case=False)]` to remove the rows that don't contain your value

The reason you get the error is because you're iterating over the df and removing rows so your indexing values become mutated and invalid

Example:

```
In [123]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'County':['Alaska', 'Big county', 'Country', 'No county', 'County']})
df[df['County'].str.contains('county', case=False)]

Out[123]:
       County
1  Big county
3   No county
4      County
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Each row has a number of columns and I need to remove those without the word "County" in the 'County' column. I tried this method and it's still leaving the target rows. For example : Alabama, A County, B, County should remove the first row which it does not appear to.

Comment: Edit your question with raw data, code to create your df, your attempts, errors and desired output

Comment: So are you after `df[~df['County'].str.contains('county')]`?

Comment: Neither remove the appropriate row from the tabe.

Comment: You can make it case insensitive `df[df['County'].str.contains('county', case=False)]` note that the normal etiquette is to post data, code and desired output rather than trying to explain ambiguous requirements

Comment: Sorry about that and thank you for being patient. The post was updated. I get the logic of filtering the data frame you've shown but, it doesn't actually remove the row without county in the appropriate column.

Comment: I don't understand you, edit your question with your code that you say doesn't work